# When using custom hook how do I get the current value before useEffect call?

Tags: reactjs

I have this issue with state update order. There's a data source, which contains some values stored by keys, and the values are constantly updated via WebSocket. And I've made a custom hook, that sets initial value from data source and subscribes to socket updates - and calls setState on any relevant update.

Then I have a form with a number input which uses the current data source value as initial form input value. For example, on component render the data source provides value "345", and then user can edit it (increase/decrease).

Now, when user selects a different data source, the input value should be reset to current data source value again - but only as a result of explicit user action - pressing a data source toggle button. Resetting it on each socket change will make the form input unusable.

The problem is when I change the data source key, the value returned from the custom hook is the old one (it only changes in useEffect).

Here's code example:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

// some data source, which has initial values and is constantly updated from socket
const data = {
  one: 12345,
  two: 23456,
};

// a simplified version of hook, which gets current value
// and subscribes to socket updates
const useMyHook = (key) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(data[key]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // set current state
    setState(data[key]);

    // subscribes/unsubscribes to socket updates, omitted for simplicity
    // ...
  }, [key]);

  return state;
};

export default function App() {
  const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState("one");

  const dataSourceValue = useMyHook(dataSource);

  const [fieldValue, setFieldValue] = useState(dataSourceValue);

  const handleDataSourceToggle = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setDataSource(dataSource === "one" ? "two" : "one");
  };

  const handleUserInput = (e) => {
    setFieldValue(e.target.value);
  };

  // input value reset - please note, that I cannot use dataSourceValue as a dependency here
  // because I don't want to lose the value entered by user - only when he explicitly changes the data source
  useEffect(() => {
    setFieldValue(dataSourceValue);
  }, [dataSource]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Custom Hook Example</h1>

      <form>
        <p>
          <input type="number" value={fieldValue} onChange={handleUserInput} />
        </p>

        <p>
          Data source: <strong>{dataSource}</strong>
        </p>
        <p>
          Data source value: <strong>{dataSourceValue}</strong>
        </p>

        <button onClick={handleDataSourceToggle}>Change data source</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This example is simplified on purpose, in reality the data source is switched in some external component, the current component receives it from React context prop.

How do I fix this?

Here's the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-brook-r9iubv?file=/src/App.js

Comment: unable to get your problem. In your example code, can u pls tell me whats the issue u facing?

Comment: The problem is when the user clicks a button and I change the data source key, the value returned from the custom hook is the old one.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, when user selects a different data source, the input value should be reset to current data source value again - but only as a result of explicit user action - pressing a data source toggle button. Resetting it on each socket change will make the form input unusable.

This isn't something that React can guess, you have to say (program) explicitly which events should change `fieldValue`, for instance by adding another `setFieldValue` in the `handleDataSourceToggle` callback.

You should also avoid this:

```
  // input value reset - please note, that I cannot use dataSourceValue as a dependency here
  // because I don't want to lose the value entered by user - only when he explicitly changes the data source
  useEffect(() => {
    setFieldValue(dataSourceValue);
  }, [dataSource]);
```

You will get eslint warnings because this is not how effects should be used. If you feel like you need to omit some dependencies, it most likely means that you should write your code differently instead.
In this particular case, I don't think you need this effect at all.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that as well, but the issue still exists - when I call `setFieldValue(dataSourceValue)` in `handleDataSourceToggle`, it uses the previous value. Do you mean there's no way to retrieve this value synchronously from a custom hook? And that I need an additional function to get current value from a data source directly in `handleDataSourceToggle `?